# Need a sample code for creating adaptive cards using node.js on emulator

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Hi can anyone help me to create adaptive cards on bot framework emulator using node.js?? and I tried the example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards on emulator but it is not creating the adaptive card.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/nwhitmont/botframework-luis-adaptive-cards-weather-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AdaptiveCard is just a JSON that you can send as an attachment of your message.

```
 session.send(new builder.Message(session).addAttachment({
     contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
     content: // here you should put your json.
 }));
```

Examples of adaptive cards JSONs can be found on the [AdaptiveCards.io](http://adaptivecards.io) site, for example [here](http://adaptivecards.io/documentation/#create-libraries-javascript).

In the link you are mentioning, there is also [a sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards#send-an-adaptive-card).